# Rails3 - Need route to a method that increments a counter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Ok, I have a simple question.  I am new to RoR and I created a scaffold for an item.  I then wanted to add a link that, when pressed, incremented a counter.  What I am having trouble with is routing.  I modeled this functionality after the destroy/delete link and method.  Here is my code:

index.html.erb:

```
  ...
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'increment', post, method: :increment%></td>
  ...
```

post_controller.rb:

```
  def vote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.counts = @post.counts + 1
    @post.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

When I try and click on the link, I get a routing error:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [POST] "/posts/25"

is there a step I am missing? Do I have to add some routing stuff to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, hang in here with me, there's a few fixes needed:

The `:method` param in the `link_to` function is not referring to the controller method, it is referring to the HTTP method. So acceptable values would be ':post', ':delete' etc.

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

In this case we probably want to set `:method` to `:post` for the increment link, which we will need to match with the route we will create now.

To access the vote action you have created, we need to add it to the routes file. You probably have something like this:

```
 resources :posts
```

We need to add an action (vote), that will apply to a member of the posts resource, so we change that to this:

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    post 'vote'
  end
end
```

Now that we have the correct route, we can use the route helper method in the `link_to` helper (to see a full list of routes run `rake routes` at the command line). So in your `link_to` replace `post` with `vote_post_path(post)`. If we include our earlier change about the `:method` we get:

```
<%= link_to 'increment', vote_post_path(post), method: :post %>
```

Hope this helps to fill in some blanks for you!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you haven't added posts as a resource to your config/routes.rb file. Try adding this line:

```
map.resources :posts
```

You might have to restart the server after you make the change.